# Should the StackOverflow FAQ point to other relevant sites?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

I Googled my way to StackOverflow searching for the answer to a question.  StackOverflow is not the right site (my question is about finding an app, not programming one).  I know there are bunches of technical StackExchange sites, but I didn't see any mentioned in the FAQ.  I don't want to ask an inappropriate question and wait for somebody to migrate it, which seems to leave browsing the full SE site list.  I can do that, but should we provide some hints?  (I'm assuming that StackOverflow, being long-established and full of questions, gets a lot of Google traffic from people who might not even know to go search the SE directory.)

Comment: "my question is about finding an app, not programming one" - be careful here. Shopping and Recommendation questions are considered off topic on all of the Stack Exchange network, see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/  and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96870/do-you-get-irked-by-the-attitude-on-se/96875#96875

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does already, per

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

> If your question is about the site itself, please don't ask it here. Visit our meta-discussion site where you can talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags should be used, suggest a feature, point out a bug, or generally discuss how Stack Overflow works.
>
> If your question would be of interest to …
>
> - System administrators and desktop support professionals, ask on Server Fault.
> - Computer enthusiasts and power users, ask on Super User.
> - Pro webmasters, ask on Webmasters.
> - Professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development, ask on Programmers.

Where the latter part is defined by the valid migration paths on that particular site.

Comment: Whoops, I totally missed that "show more" link.  Yeah, never mind -- already covered.